# Pictures won't fit in the row

Tags: html, css

Picture wont fit in the same row as.
It will all fit if its the same picture.
I've tried reducing the width of the pictures but it doesn't seem to work.
Must I make the pictures smaller?

picture of the problem -https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E9zo.png

Html

```
 <section class="section-team" id="team">
    <div class="row">
       <h2>team members</h2>    
    </div>
  <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg"  class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="column-4">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="column-12">
    <img src="img/upm.jpg" class="upm" alt="upm" style="width:20%">
    <h4>In partnership with  Upm</h4>
  </div>       
</section>
```

Css

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.column-4 {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  width: 33.3%; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.column-12 { 
  float: right; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  width: 100%; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px; 
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.section-team{
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
}

.members{
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.upm {
  float: right ; 
  padding-top: 2px;

}
```

I hope someone can show how to make the pictures fit

Comment: Consider to use flexbox, i think can solve your problems

Comment: does all the images have same size (width x height) ?

Answer (score 2):

Using flex is the probably the best and easiest solution for your problem. You can do that by declaring:

```
display:flex;
```

In the container of the photos. In your current HTML, it had to be added to the **section tag**. What flex will do, is to "force" every element to be in the same row. As it is implicit that the **flex-direction** property, is **set to row**.

Comment: I mean, in ur CSS, you do: 

section{
    display:flex
}

Answer (score 2):

Your layout is a classic grid, there are a ton of libraries that help with these kind of stuff!

Consider using Bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

If you still want to use purely CSS, I would suggest using flexbox - https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic grid system, better to use Bootstrap to get perfect grids.
Using [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">place your image here</div>
  <div class="col-4">place your image here</div>
  <div class="col-4">place your image here</div>
  <div class="col-4">place your image here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this part of code

```
    <div class="column-12">
      <img src="img/upm.jpg" class="upm" alt="upm" style="width:20%">
      <h4>In partnership with  Upm</h4>
    </div>
```

'column-12' occupies all the space in row. Above for all images you are using 'column-4'.
Or 
Use Bootstrap

Comment: What do you mean all the space in row? as in the third row?

Comment: Row contain maximum size of 12 units. column-12, column-6, column-4, column-3   These are different sizes do you want to show in single row. single row contains max size 12. If one row contains column-12 then whole row will with that column